# Flutter 3.0 : Execution failed for task ':pay_android:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, package, payment, flutter-3.0

in FLutter 3.0 facing error while implimeting gpay in flutter with pay package.

```
e: /Users/karmaln/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (50, 69): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
e: /Users/karmaln/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (69, 74): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Users/karmaln/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (73, 34): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Map<String, Any>?
e: /Users/karmaln/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_android-1.0.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/pay_android/PayMethodCallHandler.kt: (74, 34): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Map<String, Any>?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pay_android:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

> I Want to implement googlepay and Apple using pay: ^1.0.8 package

> kotlin version used in project :  ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

> min SDK version : minSdkVersion 21

Comment: have you tried by flutter clean and then flutter pub upgrade and run app again ?

Comment: Yes , But still showing same error also I have make compiledsdkversion to 31 and other instruction given over here from google : https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/setup

Comment: did you change  compileSdkVersion to 31  and try ?

Comment: yes already tried

Answer (score 0):

**Open project level build.gradle then replace your ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32' with new version.**

Comment: Yes i upgrade and now it's '1.6.**' but still not working

Comment: @PrajapatiAmit it is not related to this question, open a new issue